# how to login wandb with another acount using colab?

Tags: authentication, google-colaboratory, wandb

For example, I have A, B acounts.

First, I log in Google Colab with A account.
and I want to log in wandb with B acounts. ( using !wandb login )
is it possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you the following commands to force a relogin:

- from terminal

```
wandb login --relogin
```

- Using the API:

```
import wandb
wandb.login(relogin=True)
```

Comment: wow Thanks a lot! this is my first question on stackoverflow. haha